# No output in the paragraph after running the HTML and JS script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created a HTML code to accept pricipal, rate of interest and no of months from the users and retun the monthly payment in the paragraph with id="payment". But i am getting no value with i click the button. What have is done wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
  </title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="description" content="
">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-position: top left;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    h1 {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      color: #000000;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    p {
      font-family: Georgia, serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      color: #000000;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Finding the monthly payment</h1>
  <p>P is principal</p>
  <p>n is total no of payments</p>
  <p>i is monthly interest rate</p>
  <p>p is payment</p>
</body>
```

I have created forms for principal, interest rate and no. of months.

```
<form>
    <label for="Principal">Principal</label><br /> 
    <input name="Principal" type="number" id="Principal" /> <br /> 
    <label for="interest_rate">interest rate</label><br /> 
    <input name="interest rate" type="number" id="interest_rate" /> <br /> 
    <label for="No_of_payments">No of payments</label><br /> 
    <input name="No_of_payments" type="number" id="No_of_payments" /> <br /> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

button to run the script and reflect the value in the paragraph with id="payment".

```
<button type="button" onclick="Payment()">Find the Payment</button>
<p id="payment"></p>
<script>
function Payment() {
  let P=document.getElementById("Principal").innerHTML;
  let n=document.getElementById("No_of_payments").innerHTML;
  let i=document.getElementById("interest_rate").innerHTML;
  let p= (i*P)/(1-(Math.pow((1+i),-n)));
  document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML=p;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the page.
[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a lower case `p`

```js
document.getElementById("payment").innerHTML=p;
```

And convert your strings to numbers.

```js
let p= (parseFloat(i)*parseFloat(P))/(1-(Math.pow((1+parseFloat(i)),-parseInt(n)));
```

Comment: I am still getting no result after changing the value of p. But in the forms I have set `type="number"`.

Comment: when you pull out the inner html, it is a string, even if you set the element to a numeric type

Comment: Also check your console error log for a math error.  I left out a parenthesis, just added it...